# how to group products dynamicaly and add same product separately into the cart page?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shipping, addtocart, shopping-cart

I have some products which are selected on front end by the customer and want to make the group of that selected product and add to cart as a single view.
 **How to add same product separately into the cart page?** 
**example of cart view page which I want after adding the selected product to cart:**

grouped productname 1
selected product1 
selected product2 
selected product3 selected product2 X 3 qty 
selected product4 selected product2 x 3 qty 
Total -25874 
QTY- 1

grouped productname2
selected product6 
selected product2 
selected product8 selected product2 X 3 qty 
selected product9 selected product2 x 3 qty 
Total -85745 
QTY- 1

 Give me some solution.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand your requirements. Did you try bundle products? If so, what should be different?